# local variable 'search_keyword' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset

I have been working on a search form and it's giving me this error when i open the url or submit the form.
I am watching a codemy django tutorial and the only thing that is different is that i have some code for pagination i don't know if that's what is affecting it.

base.html

```
<div class="header-search-wrapper novis_search">
                    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'listing' %}"  name="searchform">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="custom-form">
                            <label>Keywords </label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Property Keywords" name="search"/>
                            <!-- <label >Categories</label>
                            <select data-placeholder="Categories" name = "home_type" class="chosen-select on-radius no-search-select" >
                                <option>All Categories</option>
                                <option>Single-family</option>
                                <option>Semi-detached</option>
                                <option>Apartment</option>
                                <option>Townhomes</option>
                                <option>Multi-family</option>
                                <option>Mobile/Manufactured</option>
                                <option>Condo</option>
                            </select>
                            <label style="margin-top:10px;" >Price Range</label>
                            <div class="price-rage-item fl-wrap">
                                <input type="text" class="price-range" data-min="10000" data-max="100000000000"  name="price-range1"  data-step="1" value="1" data-prefix="$₦">
                            </div> -->
                            <button  type="submit"  class="btn float-btn color-bg"><i class="fal fa-search"></i> Search</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
                </div>
```

views.py

```
def listing(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'searchform' in request.POST : 
        search = request.POST['search']
        print(search)
        propertys = Property.objects.filter(name__icontains=search)
        p = Paginator(Property.objects.order_by('-listed_on'), 2)
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        propertys = p.get_page(page)
        nums = "p" * propertys.paginator.num_pages

        return render(request, 'listing.html',{'search_keyword':search,'nums':nums,'propertys':propertys})
    else:
        p = Paginator(Property.objects.order_by('-listed_on'), 2)
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        propertys = p.get_page(page)
        nums = "p" * propertys.paginator.num_pages
        return render(request, 'listing.html',{'propertys':propertys, 'nums':nums})
```

Comment: Your function returns `search_keyword` outside the `if` statement. Therefore the value of `search_keyword` does not exist.

Comment: @NaufalHilmiaji thank you it's no longer showing the error but now it doesn't give me the search results

Comment: Try debugging each line of codes by printing the value of every variable. Also, make sure the `if` statement satisfies the condition.

Comment: @NaufalHilmiaji i tried printing search_keyword it's not getting the value

Comment: Please attach the print result image of `request.POST` to your question. I'm afraid your `POST` request form did not work properly.

Comment: it's not giving anything in the terminal

Comment: Are you using some kind of script to send the form?  This `<button onclick="location.href='listing'"` looks like it would just try to go to a url when clicked, submitting nothing.  Did I miss a `<input type='submit' ...>` somewhere?

Comment: Then the problem might be in your form. The data was never passed to the `action` URL.

Comment: @raphael I suspect the same thing, the submit button was never "submitted."

Comment: @raphael i already removed the onclick funtion

Comment: Update your question with what you have now, then.  Did you replace this input with an input type submit?

Comment: Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/listing
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8000
Referrer Policy: same-origin

Comment: this is the network header above

Comment: Update your view and template, not the network header.

Comment: yeah, i'm just checking if it submitted the form and it did